# Eclipse Oxygen This compilation unit is not on build path of java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-kafka-streams

I have created a Kafka Streams Project using Maven Archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.kafka \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=streams-quickstart-java \
-DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 \
-DgroupId=streams.examples \
-DartifactId=streams.examples \
-Dversion=0.1 \
-Dpackage=myapps
```

Compiling and running the program:

```
> mvn clean package
> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=myapps.Pipe
```

The program works fine.

However when I am editing the code and try `Ctrl+Space` I am getting `Cannot perform operation` error:

```
This compilation unit is not on build path of java project.
```

**See the image below:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

in the project directory and refresh your project in eclipse: `File -> Refresh`